# inserting multiple values in mysql table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form that submits check boxes to a PHP PDO script.  I have code that is as follows to store the values into a mysql table

```
$stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO group_members(g_id, em_id) 
                         VALUES(:g_id,:em_id) 
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE g_id = :g_id,  em_id = :em_id");
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $email) {
  $stmt->bindParam(':g_id', $gid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':em_id', $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number'

This generates an error.  What is the best way  to insert multiple values into a mysql table with different values?

Comment: Best way is to read a manual `You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every named placeholder have to be unique!

```
$stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO group_members(g_id, em_id) VALUES(:g_id,:em_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE g_id = :g_id2,  em_id = :em_id2");

$email=null;
//just bind once, that the logic behind 'bind()'
$stmt->bindParam(':g_id', $gid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':em_id', $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':g_id2', $gid , PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':em_id2', $email , PDO::PARAM_STR);

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $email) {
    $stmt->execute();//write your rows
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `//just bind once, that the logic behind 'bind()'` is the key to this question. Hope this helps someone. There was no good information there for me to make this assessment. Although @ face value now it seems obvious. The statement executes with the current values of the bind parameters set by the loop. So the current value of $email set by the loop is what the statement uses `without explict definition of the bind parameteres inside the loop.`  Ofcource values cannot be reused without `emulation mode on` being the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse placeholder names. You have to create new ones, or use VALUES in your update portion:

```
$stmt = $dbPDO->prepare("INSERT INTO group_members(g_id, em_id) VALUES(:g_id,:em_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE g_id = VALUES(g_id),  em_id = VALUES(em_id)");
```

Comment: This is mostly correct. If you have emulation mode on, then you can reuse placholders

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse a placeholder unless you have [emulation mode](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) turned on.

Generally speaking, PDO_MYSQL should have emulation on by default. The reason being that MySQL performs poorly with prepared statements. Emulation works significantly faster.

That said, if it is not on for whatever reason, you can set it manually using:

```
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,true);
```

In fact, if you are not sure, just set it anyway.

Comment: Was noted in a comment from u_mulder.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - And comments are to be treated as ephemeral, so I'm making it an answer.

Comment: I guess i can get someone around here that tells you, your answer can be a comment. ;) A quick comment. But an good answer would also tell what to do if _emulation mode turned off_ :) But nervermind. OB seems  not to  reply at all. ;)

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions - Chill out man. I'm working on it. The quick answer was just so OP didn't think that he was SOL from the other answers. It seems I needn't have worried, but still.